# Using try-except sentence in python with tenacity doesn't retry as expected

Tags: python, python-tenacity

Hi there i'm trying to use tenacity for sending an email, the script is the following:

```
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL, SMTP

@retry(stop = stop_after_attempt(7))
def email_tables(mails_to_list, smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_user, smtp_pass, tables):

    try:
            #ENVIO DE DATOS

            #Lista de mails a enviar la info
            mails_to = mails_to_list
            msg = (f"From: {smtp_user}\r\nSubject: Daily app status\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n" % (", ".join(mails_to)))

            for table in tables:
                msg = msg + table + "\r\n\r\n"

            print(msg)

            with SMTP(host = smtp_host, port = smtp_port) as smtp:
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login(user = smtp_user, password = smtp_pass)
                smtp.sendmail(from_addr = smtp_user, to_addrs = mails_to, msg = msg)
                smtp.quit()

    except Exception:
        print(Exception)
```

The thing is that if i run `email_tables(vars)` the output runs only once the method and then exits the script.

If i remove the try-except sentence and don't print the Exception the script runs 7 times as expected and then raises the error.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here in order for retry to work. Later i would like to save a log in a file when exception is raised, ideally with how many times it failed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, interesting, you might need to call `raise` after printing the exception, to rethrow it

Comment: Does it ever work? Or does it always retry then fail?

Comment: And what is the full error messageof the exception?

Comment: @barny i put wrong credentials in order to make it fail on porpouse. If i print an instance of the exception the output is: `(535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')`. The code never retries, it prints the exception once and then it finishes

Comment: @IronMan I raised the instance of the exception and it worked! thanks a lot! Just because i'm curious do you know what was happening?

Comment: By rethrowing it, you pass the exception to retry so it can detect failure occurred.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that all i needed to do is add a raise sentence with the exception for retry to be able to read it. Final code:

```
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL, SMTP

@retry(stop = stop_after_attempt(7))
def email_tables(mails_to_list, smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_user, smtp_pass, tables):

    try:
            #ENVIO DE DATOS

            #Lista de mails a enviar la info
            mails_to = mails_to_list
            msg = (f"From: {smtp_user}\r\nSubject: Daily app status\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n" % (", ".join(mails_to)))

            for table in tables:
                msg = msg + table + "\r\n\r\n"

            print(msg)

            with SMTP(host = smtp_host, port = smtp_port) as smtp:
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login(user = smtp_user, password = smtp_pass)
                smtp.sendmail(from_addr = smtp_user, to_addrs = mails_to, msg = msg)
                smtp.quit()

    except Exception:
        print(Exception)
        raise(Exception)
```